# Objective-C id & NSObject

Tags: objective-c, object, nsobject

I understand that id is for any Object type even objects that do not inherit NSObject such as things from Cocoa. I have been told to almost always use id but what if I were making an API and had a method that I wanted to make it clear that it should only take a certain type of object such an object called Animal, would I still use

```
(id) animal
```

or would I do

```
(Animal) animal
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Whoever told you to "almost always use `id`" was wrong.  Use a specific type if you have it.  Where you want to use `id` is when you get an ambiguous type back from, say an NSDictionary objectForKey.  If it's declared `id` the compiler won't complain about calling a method the type doesn't support.

Comment: @HotLicks - "ambiguous"? ;-)

Comment: Also: "things from Cocoa" essentially all inherit from NSObject too.

Comment: Revoke the coding license from whoever said to "almost always use `id`". Oops, no license; we are, after all, not professionals. :-)

Comment: @CRD - Yes.  Eg, if one has an NSDictionary from deserialized JSON the entry "Status" may be an NSString, an NSDIctionary, an NSArray, or an NSNumber.  So one would retrieve "Status" into a variable typed `id` and test it (with `isKindOfClass`), then operations on any of the above could be performed on the `id` without the need to cast to the perceived type.

Comment: @HotLicks - I was commenting on the word! I don't think something can be of *ambiguous* type; it might be *unknown*, *imprecise*, *non-specific*, etc., but surely not *ambiguous*.

Comment: @CRD - Maybe, maybe not.

Comment: @HotLicks If it were 1992, *use id* would be sound advice. ;)

Comment: Or if you were writing in C#.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen - `NSProxy`? Technically Foundation, but that division is often not stressed.

Comment: @CRD, yes, NSProxy was the reason for "essentially" in my comment. I started to mention it, but thought it was more likely to confuse the issue, and especially for a beginner, it's pretty obscure and unlikely to be encountered/needed.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen - Confusion? I'm tempted to be uncertain, and say maybe, maybe not; or ambiguous, and agree and disagree; all while dreaming of 1992, C# and coding licenses... :-) It was fun, enough I tell myself.

Answer (score 6):

`id` is a generic pointer to an object -- it's like `void *`, except that the pointer *must* point to an Objective-C object. So yes, you *could* use `id` in most situations where a more specific object pointer type would work, but it's usually better to use the more specific type:

```
- (id)animal;  // OK if 'animal' could be any type of object
- (Animal*)animal; // much better if you know that 'animal' points to an object of type 'Animal'
```

You'll find plenty of examples if you look at any Cocoa or Cocoa Touch class. Let's look at a little bit of [`UIView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1):

```
- (BOOL)isDescendantOfView:(UIView *)view;  // returns YES for self.
- (UIView *)viewWithTag:(NSInteger)tag;     // recursive search. includes self
```

As you can see, the first method takes a `UIView*` as a parameter. If you try to pass something other than a pointer to an instance of `UIView`, the compiler will complain.

The second method returns a `UIView*`, and you can use the result directly as the receiver of other messages that `UIView` understands:

```
[[topView viewWithTag:someTag] removeFromSuperview];
```

Being specific about the types of parameters and return values lets the compiler help you make sure that you're sending appropriate messages to your objects and getting appropriate values back.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any type starting from `Animal` and then up through inheritance chain to `NSObject` and `id`. Any would be valid. But in most cases you need to use just `Animal` because this is the very type you need to work with